# What is the correct/recommended way of triggering events and callbacks during a process?

Tags: c#, events, callback, architecture

I'm in charge of the architecture of an internal codebase/SDK. We are conflicted about how to standardize the order of triggering callbacks and events inside the API. There are two cases we're concerned about.

```
class Foo {

    public event Action StuffDone;

    public void DoStuff(Action callback) {

        StuffDone?.Invoke();
        callback?.Invoke();

    }

}
```

We've realized that sometimes the order of invoking the event and the callback is reversed, and it seems very inconsistent, but we can't find any resources to back up one way of ordering or the other.

There are two reasonings presented:

1. Call the `event` *before* `callback`, because `event` is a part of the process, and the `callback` is just a signal of the process being finished for the caller.
2. Call the `event` *after* the `callback`, because the caller of the method/invoker of the process should be notified first about the process completion, not other entities (through the `event`).

Will appreciate all the feedback and resources!

Comment: Use one _or_ the other, not both. They are redundant.

Answer (score 0):

You want to make it explicit. The fact is when you invoke behavior matters. This means you should think about how your event will be used and design accordingly. Do you want one, the other, or both? In any case try and make the name of the event very explicit.

```
public event Action BeforeStuff;
public event Action AfterStuff;

public void DoStuff(Action callback) 
{
    if (callback == null)
        throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(callback));
    BeforeStuff?.Invoke();
    callback();
    AfterStuff?.Invoke();
}
```